# Binding To Collections And Maps

Tags: grails, documentation

In grails documentation: 7 The Web Layer - Reference Documentation, section: Binding To Collections And Maps; the next example is shown:

```
class Album {
    String title
    static hasMany = [players: Player]
    Map players
}
class Player {
    String name
}

def bindingMap = [title: 'The Lamb Lies Down On Broadway',
                  'players[guitar]': [name: 'Steve Hackett'],
                  'players[vocals]': [name: 'Peter Gabriel']
                  'players[keyboards]': [name: 'Tony Banks']]
def album = new Album(bindingMap)

assert album.title == 'The Lamb Lies Down On Broadway'
assert album.players.size() == 3
assert album.players.guitar == 'Steve Hackett'
assert album.players.vocals == 'Peter Gabriel'
assert album.players.keyboards == 'Tony Banks'

def updatedBindingMap = ['players[drums]': [name: 'Phil Collins'],
                         'players[keyboards]': [name: 'Anthony George Banks']]

album.properties = updatedBindingMap

assert album.title == 'The Lamb Lies Down On Broadway'
assert album.players.size() == 4
assert album.players.guitar == 'Steve Hackett'
assert album.players.vocals == 'Peter Gabriel'
assert album.players.keyboards == 'Anthony George Banks'
assert album.players.drums == 'Phil Collins'
```

But, when I run this example as a Unit Test fails with next result (very below is my unit test):

|Loading Grails 2.3.11
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to test
........................................
|Running without daemon...
| Compiling 1 source files.
| Running 1 unit test... 1 of 1
| Running 1 unit test... 2 of 2
| Failure:  test constructor binding with insert and updating(estudio.AlbumSpec)
|  Condition not satisfied:
album.players.guitar == 'Steve Hackett'
|     |       |      |
|     |       |      false
|     |       [name:Steve Hackett]
|     [keyboards:[name:Tony Banks], vocals:[name:Peter Gabriel], guitar:[name:Steve Hackett]]
estudio.Album : (unsaved)
    at estudio.AlbumSpec.test constructor binding with insert and updating(AlbumSpec.groovy:51)
| Completed 2 unit tests, 1 failed in 0m 1s
| Tests FAILED  - view reports in /Users/hzendejas/my-grails-projects/estudio/target/test-reports
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error

But success when I modify assert adding .name property as next:

album.players.guitar.name == 'Steve Hackett'

Is it right Grails documentation or what I do not know???

PD: my successful unit test:

```
package estudio

import grails.test.mixin.TestMixin
import grails.test.mixin.support.GrailsUnitTestMixin
import spock.lang.Specification

/**
 * See the API for {@link grails.test.mixin.support.GrailsUnitTestMixin} for usage instructions
 */
@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
class AlbumSpec extends Specification {

    void "test constructor binding with insert and updating"() {
        given:
        def bindingMap =
                [title: 'The Lamb Lies Down On Broadway',
                    'players[guitar]': [name: 'Steve Hackett'],
                    'players[vocals]': [name: 'Peter Gabriel'],
                    'players[keyboards]': [name: 'Tony Banks']
                ]

        def updatedBindingMap = [
            'players[drums]': [name: 'Phil Collins'],
            'players[keyboards]': [name: 'Anthony George Banks']
        ]

        when:
        def album = new Album(bindingMap)

        then:
        album.title == 'The Lamb Lies Down On Broadway'
        album.players.size() == 3
        album.players.guitar.name == 'Steve Hackett'
        album.players.vocals.name == 'Peter Gabriel'
        album.players.keyboards.name == 'Tony Banks'

        when:
        album.properties = updatedBindingMap

        then:
        album.title == 'The Lamb Lies Down On Broadway'
        album.players.size() == 4
        album.players.guitar.name == 'Steve Hackett'
        album.players.vocals.name == 'Peter Gabriel'
        album.players.keyboards.name == 'Anthony George Banks'
        album.players.drums.name == 'Phil Collins'
    }

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test something"() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Closing question: I have just realised that grails documentation itself is wrong because in a previous example, above the example subject of my question, property .name is effectively indicated in the asserts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a mistake in the docs.  I just fixed that.  See https://github.com/grails/grails-doc/commit/a6df1a7a2cbfbd413fb8f49c8d33bc29ff26c947.

Thanks for the feedback.  Sorry for the trouble.